# How to change the display language in Xbox Games on Windows Phone

Tags: 8.0, games, language-setting, xbox-live

I tried adding a Game using the Windows Phone Store to my account. The game requirex XBox Games. A simple account on Xbox was created, but it is in the wrong display language (french). I need to change it to Dutch.

How can I do this on my Windows Phone?

Comment: Have you tried changing the phone language at Settings > Language?